# Laravel 8 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Всем привет! Проблема следующая, когда пытаюсь сделать любой запрос к базе выдает ошибку SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused, при этом миграции работают без проблем. Пробовал менять 127.0.0.1 на localhost - ошибка остается, миграции отваливаются. Заменял на mysql, все по-прежнему, миграции не работают. Миграции работают только с DB_HOST=127.0.0.1, но при этом не работают запросы. С DB_HOST=localhost не работает ничего. Помогите кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, недавно начал изучать Laravel, поэтому вообще понятия не имею куда копать и что еще пробовать, заранее спасибо!

docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '12345'
            MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '12345'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laradb'
        volumes:
            - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin1
        environment:
         - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8081:80
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: mysql
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        platform: linux/x86_64
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
    
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
    mysqldata: {}
```

Мой код:

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laradb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=12345
```

Проект разрабатывается в Docker на MacOS BigSur. По умолчанию на ОС чем-то забит порт 3306, поэтому использую в Докере 3307, работает с БД только так и это проверенно уже не одним проектом. Собственно миграции заработали только когда вписал 3307 (сразу просто забыл поменять), а вот запросы к БД ни с каким не работают.

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laradb'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '12345'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Также пробовал писать значение в database.php точно такие же как в .env, пробовал оставлять по умолчанию - ничего не помогло. Оставил вот так.

Добавил в базу запись, пытаюсь вывести таким образом:

```
Route::get('/test', function (){
    $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();

    return $posts;
});
```

Также пробовал такой вариант, чтобы добавить данный в БД,просто может не правильно вывожу и считываю, я уже ни в чем не уверен)))

```
DB::insert('insert into posts(title, content) values(?, ?)', ['Laravel News', 'Some text about Laravel']);
```

Comment: Порт 3307, меняли с дефолтного в настройках mysql?

Comment: У меня MacOS, по умолчанию 3306 чем-то забит, поэтому использую Docker с портом 3307, локальная БД работает только так. Ну по идее не в порте дело, так как я с Докером уже на чистом php не один проект сделал и спокойно с этим портом подключаюсь к БД и к phpmyadmin, вряд ли Laravel какой-то особенный в этом плане, но могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: Если с другими проектами работает, то в принципе да, и тут должно. Предложу стандартно почистить кеш конфига и просто кеш (`php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear` ) и попробовать еще раз

Comment: Это делал и даже комбинацию route:clear, config:clear, cash:clear. На самом деле уже кучу таких вопросов пересмотрел, но пока решения найти никак не могу(

Comment: Покажите команду которой вы запускаете контейнер

Comment: У меня сборка, проект запускаю через docker-compose up. Все проекты так запускаю, все работает, ну и здесь миграции работают, а запросы нет и вот это меня удивляет

Comment: @Tuchyn2511 покажите файл docker-compose.yaml, действительно нужно указывать хост контейнера для доступа к базе внутри докера

Comment: @lezhni добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Tuchyn2511 вместо DB_HOST попробуй указать mysql (имя контейнера), должно сработать

Comment: @lezhni попробовал, вылазит ошибка SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `posts`), миграции перестали работать

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас DB в docker контейнере, то в качестве DB_HOST необходимо указывать имя этого docker контейнера.

Comment: Ну если сделать проброс портов то можно и через `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Укажите в `.env` не DB_PORT=3307, а **DB_PORT=3306** в *вашем случае*.
Здесь должен указываться порт, который в docker-compose.yml вы указываете **вторым**.

```
mysql:
    ...
    ports:
        - 3307:3306
    ...
```